# Golang sql driver, why do we need to pass a slice of a byte array as an arguement to the query

Tags: go

I am validating a hash from a mariadb database, and I'm unsure of why I have to take a slice of an array, instead of passing just the array.

I am hashing the token in golang like this:

```golang
// This type is a [32]uint8
tokenHash := sha256.Sum256(([]byte(token)))
```

Then I'm trying to match the token hash to the hash saved in the database here

```golang
// tokenHash[:] is of type []uint8
err := m.DB.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, tokenHash[:], time.Now())
```

The error I get if I don't take a slice is: `sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type [32]uint8, a array`

I have it working, but I just don't understand why it's working.

The sql if interesed is

```
    query := `SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email
                        FROM
                                users u
                        INNER JOIN tokens t on (u.id = t.user_id)
                        WHERE t.token_hash = ?
                        and t.expiry > ?
    `
```

I checked the types here:
https://play.golang.org/p/5xUAgv_sdfA

Comment: []uint8 is an alias for []byte. Are you asking why []byte is supported but [32]byte isn't? That's because there's no reason to. []byte covers all byte array types already.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on why []uint8 is a supported type, and [32]uint8 is not. They seem to be the same to me except ones an array and the other is a slice.

Comment: Both byte slices and byte arrays represent a sequence of bytes, but slices don't prescribe the length, so they are the more general type. Supporting the general type is enough. Put yourself in the shoes of the driver author. If you wanted to support arrays directly, how do you decide *which* arrays you want to support. [32]? [16]? What about [17] or [145]? Where do you stop? These are all distinct types, and for each one you'd have to have a case in a type switch. It's kind of pointless to deal with this, because a slice covers all of them already and you have to support them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

An array is not a slice. An array [n]Type is a data type that has `n` items of `Type`, which is different from `[m]Type`, if `m!=n`. That is, if there is a function:

```
f(args [8]byte)
```

you cannot pass `[9]byte` to it. Those are two different types.

Arrays are passed by value. For instance, when you call `f(arr)`, all elements of `arr` are passed to `f`, not a reference to the `arr`.

A slice is a view over an array. It can grow as necessary. When you pass a slice to a function, you pass a triple (len,cap,pointer to array).

That's the reason why when you pass an array to a function that needs a slice, you have to create a slice from that array first.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, I understand the differences between an Array and a slice, but method is taking the type ```...interface{}``` for the query arguments. so in that case we need to pass a type the database column is expecting (string in this case)

Comment: I guess the error `sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type [32]uint8, a array` should be my clue here 

It seems that it's trying to convert to a string, using type assertion? I tested with this
https://play.golang.org/p/mGpVZiWlmQ7
```
func check(args ...interface{}) {
 for _, item := range args {
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", string(item.([]uint8)))
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't say it is expecting a string. It only says it is not expecting an array. Looks like a slice is acceptable though, which is expected. Arrays have somewhat limited and very specific use cases.